# MVC Validation Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am receiving this error when user does not enter information into the form. It is required for the user to enter a title and body for a new article. When they do not enter a body or title, this exception is thrown. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `ModelState.IsValid`.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Save the record
}

else
{
    // Show the View with errors highlighted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch block and to catch the entity validation error you have to use this catch block :

```
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Try to debug this inner foreach loop using breakpoint, this way you can get the exact validation error of an entity.

Note : The error is rrlated with Database entity like varchar(50) is defined but excedding the limit etc.